# need help : How to get user add images in folder and it automatically declares them

Tags: javascript, arrays

At the moment there are some images but at the same time im declaring for additional images with no images, so when the user places the image and names the images what i given to the blank images it will replace and overwrite the blank image

Im trying to figure how can i skip the blank images when the user is playing slideshow on web page and play with images. I tried many different options but i failed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HR Slideshow</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="js/sliderEffects.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        #info {
            width: 900px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            color: #434343;
        }
        #info #logo {
            float: right;
            width: 100px;
            margin-top: -60px;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #7b7b7b;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #4d4d4d;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="slider" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; margin: auto;">
        <img src="images/1.jpg"  alt="HR Slideshow" class="sliderImage" >
    </div>



    <script>
        //fullScreen () ;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var images = ["images/1.jpg" , "images/2.jpg" , "images/3.jpg",  "images/4.jpg",  "images/5.jpg" ];
var timing = 3000;
var currentImg = 1;

function karrotSlider() {
    
    var nextimg = (currentImg + 1) > images.length ? 1 : currentImg + 1;
      
    var effect = Math.floor (Math.random()*8 +1 );
    
    //effect=1;

    switch (effect) {
        case 1: 
            KSDissolve(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 2:
            KSSlideUp(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 3:
            KSSlideDown(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 4:
            KSSlideLeft(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 5:
            KSSlideRight(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 6:
            KSMosaic(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 7:
            KSWindows(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
        case 8:
            KSDo(images[currentImg- 1], images[nextimg- 1])
            break;
    }

    currentImg = (currentImg + 1) > images.length ? 1 :  currentImg + 1;
    
}

window.onload = setInterval(function () { karrotSlider() } , timing);
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider::after {
    clear: both;
}

.dissolve {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-animation: dissolveAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: dissolveAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: dissolveAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.slideUp {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-animation: slideUpAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: slideUpAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: slideUpAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.slideDown {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-animation: slideDownAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: slideDownAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: slideDownAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.slideLeft {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-animation: slideLeftAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz -animation: slideLeftAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: slideLeftAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.slideRight {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-animation: slideRightAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz -animation: slideRightAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: slideRightAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


.mosaicBlock {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: myfirst 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


.windowBlock {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-animation: windowAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: windowAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: windowAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.imagePush {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-animation: imagePushAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: imagePushAnimation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: imagePushAnimation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.imagePush2 {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-animation: imagePush2Animation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: imagePush2Animation 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: imagePush2Animation 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

/* 
Animations
*/


/*Dissolve Animation */

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes dissolveAnimation {
    from {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes dissolveAnimation {
    from {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes dissolveAnimation {
    from {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/*Slide Up Animation */

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slideUpAnimation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,-500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes slideUpAnimation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,-500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slideUpAnimation {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0,-500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/*Slide Down Animation */

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slideDownAnimation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes slideDownAnimation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slideDownAnimation {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0,500px);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/*Slide Left Animation */

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftAnimation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes slideLeftAnimation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translate(-500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slideLeftAnimation {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(-500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/*Slide Right Animation */

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes slideRightAnimation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes slideRightAnimation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translate(500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slideRightAnimation {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(500px,0);
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/*Mosaic */
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes myfirst {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
     from {
        transform: scale(1,1);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


/*Windows */

@-webkit-keyframes windowAnimation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes windowAnimation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

@keyframes windowAnimation {

    from {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

/*Push */

 @-webkit-keyframes imagePushAnimation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(100px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

 @-moz-keyframes imagePushAnimation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(100px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


@keyframes imagePushAnimation {

    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(100px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(100px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}


@-webkit-keyframes imagePush2Animation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(-150px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes imagePush2Animation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -moz-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(-150px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}

@keyframes imagePush2Animation {

    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(0px,0px);
        display: block;
    }
    to {
         -ms-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-150px,0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: translate(-150px,0px);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
}
```